# Is there a keyboard shortcut in RStudio to put roxygen2 denotation (#') at start of each selected line in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, roxygen2

Is there a shortcut that can add `#'` to the start of selected lines in RStudio? In a similar way to how cmd + shift + c will add `#` to the start of selected lines?

This could be quite helpful when copying in a clump (say 20 or more lines) of examples into function documentation, as putting this notation at the start of lines can otherwise be rather fiddly